# Laravel Crinsane/LaravelShoppingCart destroy() doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, package

Im having problem when trying to clear the shopping cart in Crinsane/LaravelShoppingCart , when i click the route it return a blank page with "http://localhost:81/webshop/cart/delete" URL. I think something wrong with my route naming, i can't figure out what it's . Hope someone can help me

```
Route::any('/cart/delete','CartController@delete')->name('cart.delete');
```

My route in the link when clicking it

```
<th style="width:50%">Product <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="{{route('cart.delete')}}">Clear cart<i class="fa fa-eraser"></a></th>
```

and here the function in my controller

```
public function delete(){
        Cart::destroy();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

My other function works, i can show shopping cart, edit shopping cart, delete a row in the shopping cart they work perfectly but not the clear all shopping cart(delete function)

this is the package im using https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

Comment: The truncate method is part of the Query Builder. Try: `Cart::truncate();` instead of `Cart::destroy();`

Comment: i still doesn't work but thank for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **truncate()**

```
 public function delete()
    {
        DB::table('Cart')->truncate();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

It works. But if you still have same issue you can define DELETE method under the  tags. Like this:

```
<th>
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['cart.delete', $cart->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
</th>
```

Comment: I don't have a cart table i uses the Crinsane/LaravelShoppingCart for the shopping cart so it use it custom session

Comment: i know it helpful i gave a point but it still show a blank page for me :<

Comment: Are you sure route is working well? If you are not sure. try dd(' '); in delete function.

Comment: dd(''); doesn't work too still blank page , it must be my route cause it doesn't get the function

Comment: I am saying if you are new. You need to write something in dd.
dd('blabla'); 
If page shown "blabla" route is work perfectly.
than you need to think about function.
if "blabla" is not coming to the page, you must consider about web.php
for example my delete route is:
Route::delete('page/deleting', 'MyController@deletecart')->name('deletecart');

Answer (score 2):

**instead of:**

```
Cart::destroy();
```

**use:**

```
Cart::truncate();
```

That drops all rows from the table.

**However:**

**Using `Route::any` for a destructive operation such as deleting all records is very unsafe**. 
I suggest you at least use a `post` route to handle these kinds of operations.

Comment: it still return a blank page with the same URL i think it's the route naming

Answer (score 2):

fix your route with

```
Route::any('/cart/delete/{id}','CartController@delete')->name('cart.delete');
```

And in Controller is

```
public function delete()
{
    Cart::destroy();

    return back();
}
```

On your html just give with a form action, for the example :

```
<form action="{{route('index.cart.empty', $item->rowId)}}" method="post">
     @csrf                      
     @method('DELETE')
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> CLEAR SHOPPING CART </button>                 
</form>
```

Hope it will help you